# SDRAM and I2S on STM32

Tags: stm32, audio, memory, sdram, i2s

I am using an STM32F429 discovery board to develop a DSP platform for making some sound effects. I have I2S streaming and passing through, and I have SDRAM configured where I can talk to it and even transfer my buffers on and off it.

Where I am struggling is a very peculiar behavior. When I am running the I2S buffers off the internal ram, there are no issues. When I put said buffers on the SDRAM, the I2S works for about 10 seconds before it starts to make noise, become very loud and distorted and then just hiss.

I was wondering if anyone had any idea where I might start to look for a solution? I cant imagine that the device isn't capable of what I'm asking it for 10 seconds but not after that. I am hoping there is some solution but google is proving difficult!

Source code can be found here : https://community.st.com/t5/boards-and-hardware-tools-mcus/i2s-and-sdram/td-p/579156

I believe that the SDRAM is shifted back a half word as it loses alignment with the I2S but I am struggling to verify this.

Comment: I do not think I can help you with an answer, but please add the relevant source code to the question.

Comment: I have updated my question with a link to the source code.